# DataNucleus casting serialized objects

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I have an application using DataNucleus/JDO on Google App Engine, and I'm attempting to make a pool of persisted objects so user requests can simply fetch a key instead of waiting for a new object to be persisted.

The object pool is held in an ArrayBlockingQueue<Key>, and every time a user requests a new Key I pop one from the queue and spawn a DeferredTask to persist a new object and add it to the queue in a separate thread, so the Key can be returned to the user quickly:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class EquipmentStock implements Serializable {

    ...

    @Persistent(serialized="true")
    private ArrayBlockingQueue<Key> blockingQueue;

    public Key getEquipmentKey() throws IllegalArgumentException, InterruptedException {
        Key key = blockingQueue.take();

        QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue().add(withDefaults().payload(new DeferredTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getInstance().getPersistenceManager();

                try {
                    EquipmentItemData equipmentData = ObjectFetcher.fetchObjectByID(pm, EquipmentItemData.class, equipmentID, true);
                    EquipmentItem equipmentItem = new EquipmentItem(equipmentData);

                    pm.makePersistent(equipmentItem);

                    blockingQueue.put(equipmentItem.getKey());
                }
                ...
            }
        }));

        return key;

    }
}
```

When the application shuts down/restarts, I need to save/load the contents of the queue.  GAE doesn't support persisting ArrayBlockingQueues, so I attempted to persist the queue as a serialized object, but it fails to load with a ClassCastException:

```
Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@12b17d0{...}
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.simple.Collection cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue
    at {...}.EquipmentStock.jdoReplaceField(EquipmentStock.java)
    at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.replaceField(AbstractStateManager.java:2387)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceField(JDOStateManager.java:1877)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceField(JDOStateManager.java:1781)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.createSCOWrapper(SCOUtils.java:241)
    at org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.SCOUtils.newSCOInstance(SCOUtils.java:139)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.wrapSCOField(JDOStateManager.java:2230)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.replaceAllLoadedSCOFieldsWithWrappers(JDOStateManager.java:2115)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:372)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
    at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2357)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1896)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
    at {...}.EquipmentStockLocator.initStock(EquipmentStockLocator.java:57)
    at {...}.BootstrapListener.contextInitialized(BootstrapListener.java:13)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.createHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:219)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.getHandler(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:194)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:134)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

As far as I can tell, DataNucleus is casting the ArrayBlockingQueue to its generic Collection class, but failing to cast it back when the application restarts, presumably because casting to Collection discarded ArrayBlockingQueue's fixed size data.
What I don't understand is why it's casting the ArrayBlockingQueue in the first place, since I specified that it should be stored as a single serialized blob.

Comment: since that type is a Collection it is loading up a "wrapper" for it, to intercept calls to mutator methods. You ought to write a wrapper for it and then it can construct it ok. No idea what the NPE means but then DataNucleus don't support that ancient version now anyway. And I doubt you'll ever get support from Google on their JDO/JPA plugin that is causing the problem

Comment: I already tried putting the queue in a wrapper class; any object that contains an ArrayBlockingQueue will run into the same issue when it's persisted.  Having a wrapper just means the exception gets thrown for the wrapper class instead of the main class.

Comment: No, I said a "wrapper" ... a class that DataNucleus will use to wrap the field (like providing support for it). They allow you to provide support for other types.

Comment: That was exactly the information I was looking for; I could not for my life figure out how to specify another class to use for serialization.  Thanks!